# What is a good script-driven 3d image drawing program?

Tags: image, scripting, 3d

I want to use a Makefile to produce lots of images by script in the same manner as TeX tikz.  It can be a different script language, but it should be either simple or worth the extra power.

I use graphviz and gnuplot and love them both.  Both are driven by text scripts describing what is to be drawn.  Absolutely no GUI should be necessary.

The script should be able to do the usual things like drawing a red line.

```
draw[line width=2px,color=red] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1);
```

Are there any good choices for script-driven 3D image generating programs with the look and feel of graphviz or gnuplot?